# How to reinstall ASP.NET MVC 5 WEB templates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core-mvc

I have been happily developing my MVC5 websites so far with VS.2015 Commnity Edition. For a new project I got curious about the new MVC6 aka ASP.NET 5.0 RC so I installed the package.

Right away I got problems with AVG complaining about DNX, ended up uninstalling the 5.0 RC. However, it appears it also uninstalled all my web templates (4.5.*) because now I cannot open any web project and cannot create any web project (template not showing anymore).

What do I need to do? I had a project in progress and now everything is screwed.

UPDATE
Since VS.2015 Repair did not fix anything, I used the Web API Installer 5 that is for the Azure SDK because it says it also restores the usual MVC templates. Well, that is not true.

After that, the Web subfolder in the C# Templates appeared again, it shows the ASP.NET 5 but then of the "old" one, it shows me only ASP.NET 4.5.2 Templates that are for Empty, Web Forms (not interested in ASPX), and three different Azure templates but the usual ones that were Web API and MVC are not there anymore.

Comment: That VS.2015 Update 2 really messed everything up! I have reinstalled three times and now I cannot even develop anything because VS.2015 now refuses to run. Issue reported to Microsoft.
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2664246/vs-2015-community-fails-to-start-cannot-find-one-of-its-components

Answer (score 1):

From Package Manager Console, type Uninstall-Package MVC 6 RC.  Then Install-Package MVC 5.

To open Package Manager Console, type the keyword on the search box that is on the top left of Visual Studio.

Find the correct syntax to install it from the link below:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnet.mvc/

Comment: Would that install the TEMPLATES too?

Comment: It will install all the MVC5 package.  I would suggest to follow the information on the link instead.

Comment: What I was missing was the package templates, not the DLLs. Anyway, with Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 my whole development environment got screwed up and now I cannot run VS.2015 anymore, reinstalled 4 times, same error.